# Problem with displaying transparent image on CTkCanvas

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, customtkinter

I want to display a different images in a CTkCanvas. These images are png or jpg files.
Currently this is how i am displaying the images:

```
image = 
ctk.CTkImage(dark_image=Image.open("projects/"+project_name+"/Files/"+objecttemp[4]),size= 
(100,100)) 
label = ctk.CTkLabel(viewport_canvas, text="",image=image,width=100,height=100)
label.place(x=editor_x,y=editor_y)
label.lower()
self.displayed_objects.append(label)
```

If the images are png files i want them to be transparent.
I already tried using .convert("RGBA") but it didnt work.

This is another one of my attempts:

```
            image0 = 
            Image.open("projects/"+project_name+"/Files/"+objecttemp[4])
            image1 = image0.resize((100,100))
            image_tk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image1)  
            viewport_canvas.create_image(editor_x, editor_y 
            ,image=image_tk)
```

It dindnt really work, because the image is not displayed in the canvas

Is it possible that i can use the Label and the images still being displayed with transparency?

Comment: You need to use `viewport_canvas.create_image(...)` instead of using label to put the image into the canvas.

Comment: I tried doing it but it didnt work. (I updated the question)

Comment: It works for me, so it is better to provide a [mre].

Comment: Note that tkinter widgets do not support transparent background.

Comment: I tried doing it again (using .create_image) a little bit differently. It works now thankyou so much